# Postgresql and ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a simple sql request :

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table;
```

where the column b is an array :

```
  a  | b
-----+--------
 001 | {x,y,z}
-----+--------
 002 | {x,s}
```

How can I get this result :

```
  a  | b       | c
-----+---------+---
 001 | {x,y,z} | x
-----+---------+---
 001 | {x,y,z} | y
-----+---------+---
 001 | {x,y,z} | z
-----+---------+---
 002 | {x,s}   | x
-----+---------+---
 002 | {x,s}   | s
```

where the new column 'c' represent all elements of the array. (I'm using postgres)

'a' is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a, b, UNNEST(b) AS c
FROM table;
```

UNNEST takes an array and returns a set or rows for each item in the array. This query will result in the values to the left being duplicated for each of the UNNEST rows, resulting in exactly the result you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean somethig like this ? :

```
Select
   x.val,
   unnest(x.val)
From (
   Select '{1,2,3,4}'::int[] val
) x
```